# Queue emitted values using RxJS, like it can be done with p-queue

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, queue, observable

Using [p-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue), I can limit how many times I start some asynchronous action (for instance, API requests) in a period of time, and how many of these asynchronous actions can run at once.

It works great, but I feel like I should be able to do the same thing with [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/).  I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so.  I'm still pretty new to RxJS, and I have yet to find any examples that do what I'm trying to do.

I see operators such as [`buffer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer) and [`throttleTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime), and these seem like the way to go, but I'm having difficulty putting all of this information together.

How would I replicate a [p-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue) configuration of:

```
{
    concurrency:    2 /* at a time */
    , intervalCap: 10 /* per every… */
    , interval: (  15 /* seconds */ * 1000 /* milliseconds */)
    , carryoverConcurrencyCount: true
}
```

…using [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/)?

An RxJS solution should:

- Immediately allow through values when the queue is empty (i.e. start a new interval immediately, not wait for some interval whose timing depends on when the queue was last not-empty)
- Provide the same functionality as [p-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue)'s `carryoverConcurrencyCount`: "…the task must finish in the given interval or will be carried over into the next interval count."

---

Full example using [p-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue):

```
// Queue/Concurrency-limit requests
const PQueue = require('p-queue') ;
const requestQueue = new PQueue({
    concurrency:    2 /* at a time */
    , intervalCap: 10 /* per every… */
    , interval: (  15 /* seconds */ * 1000 /* milliseconds */)
    , carryoverConcurrencyCount: true
}) ;

// From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

const queuePromises = (
    [...(Array(20)).keys()]
    .map(number => requestQueue.add(() => new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(number), getRandomInt(0, /* up to */ 250) /* milliseconds */))
    ))
) ;

queuePromises.forEach(queuePromise => queuePromise.then(
    number => console.log(number, 'resolved') 
    , error => console.error('Individual Promise error', error)
)) ;

Promise.all(queuePromises).then(
    numbers => console.log('all are resolved', ...numbers)
    , error => console.error('All Promises error', error)
) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know **p-queue** but probably you could look at `mergeMap` operator to accomplish what you want, and in particular to the `concurrency` parameter of `mergeMap`. Via `concurrency` parameter you can define how many  parallel executions you can run concurrently.

So the code, starting from your example, could be something like this

```
const concurrency = 1;
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

const queuePromises = (
    [...(Array(20)).keys()]
    .map(number => new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(number), getRandomInt(0, /* up to */ 250) /* milliseconds */)))
) ;

from(queuePromises).pipe(
  mergeMap(qp => from(qp), concurrency)
)
.subscribe(
  number => console.log(number, 'resolved') 
  , error => console.error('Individual Promise error', error),
  () => console.log('all are resolved')
)
```

Setting the value of `concurrency` to 1 allows you to see that actually you have the results of the promises arriving sequentially in an ordered way.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It gets me going in the right direction.  `mergeMap` seems to be an alias for [`flatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap), right?  Is `mergeMap` with a concurrency of `1` the same as [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap)?  I ran your code once with `concurrency = 1` and once with `concurrency = 2`, and could see the difference.

Comment: Both yes to your questions. `mergeMap` is the new name of `flatMap`. `concatMap` is `mergeMap` with concurrency set to 1.